# Ubuntu upgraded hard drive how to connect old hard drive

Tags: partitioning, mount

I've recently upgraded home server by installing a 1T drive and now I want to connect the old drive to the system. How do I go about this? I know that old drive has 2 ext2 partitions and is around 500GB and is shown as sda2 in this list.

```
lsblk shows sda2 mounted to boot
sda                         8:0    0 931.5G  0 disk 
├─sda1                      8:1    0     1M  0 part 
├─sda2                      8:2    0     1G  0 part /boot
└─sda3                      8:3    0 930.5G  0 part 
  └─ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv 253:0    0 930.5G  0 lvm  /

brw-rw---- 1 root disk 8, 16 Jun  3 13:39 /dev/sdb

fstab:
UUID=1f744f7a-55e7-4c52-ab5e-239bfac6ebe2 / ext4 defaults 0 0
UUID=0d9de09a-0c0a-49d3-8b14-581ffb4da1a0 /boot ext4 defaults 0 0

fdisk -l:

Disk /dev/sdb: 465.8 GiB, 500106780160 bytes, 976771055 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

Device     Boot Start       End   Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sdb1           1 976773167 976773167 465.8G ee GPT


mount -a -t ext2 /dev/sdb /media/old_drive/
mount the drive but not its partitions

ls -la /media/old_drive/
total 8
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Jun  2 09:34 .
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 Jun  2 09:34 ..
```

I'm not sure where to go from here :(

Mick

Comment: The mount command has an issue, try to mount the partition : `mount -t ext2 /dev/sdb1 /media/old_drive/` - This will give a try for the sdb1 partition, if OK, you can add this sdb1 to your fstab

Comment: If the above works, please let us know so @cmak.fr can post it as an answer.  If unclear: make it into an answer using /dev/sdb1 instead of the UUID and explain how to the the UUID

Comment: Thank you for your help but I get error message mount: /media/old_drive: special device /dev/sdb1 does not exist.